# Newton Raphson method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I try to do a Newton Raphson method with JS.
I did that code but, on this code the polinomy it's defined and  I need to pass manually.
I don't know how I can put a polinomy manually. Please any idea... :(

```
<script language="javascript">
        function funcion(x)
        {
            return  Math.cos(x) - x * x * x;
        }
        function derivada(x)
        {
            return -Math.sin(x) - 3.0 * x * x * x;
        }
        function procesar(formulario)
        {
            var i = 0;
            var err, x_1, x = parseFloat(formulario.x.value);
            var resultado = '<table border="1"><thead><tr><td align="center">i</td><td align="center">x<sub></sub></td><td align="center">error</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
            do
            {
                x_1 = x;
                x = x - funcion(x) / derivada(x);
                err = Math.abs((x - x_1) / x);
                resultado += '<tr><td>x<sub>' + i + '</sub></td><td>' + x_1 + '</td><td>' + err + '</td></tr>';
                i++;
            } while (x != x_1 && i < 100);
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resultado + '</tbody></table><br>' + (i == 100 ? 'La solucion no es convergente. ' : 'La solucion es ' + x);
            return false;
        }
```

That's my html:

```
<body>
  <h1 align="center">Metodo de Newton-Raphson</h1>


  <form name="formulario" onsubmit="return procesar(this);">
    Ingrese la función
    <input name="x" type="text" size="4" />
    <input type="submit" value="Procesar" />
  </form>


  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  <table align="center" bgcolor="white">
    <tr>
      <th>

        <br/>
        <div id="resultado"></div>

      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: you should change your opening script tag to use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script language="javascript">` since the latter has been deprecated for a while

Comment: are you trying to replace `Math.cos(x) - x * x * x;` with a manually entered function?

Comment: Yes, that what I need..

Comment: who is going to give you that function? other code? the user?

Comment: if the user is knowledgeable enough to type the function in javascript you could use **eval** to interpret the inputted string to a js function. :)

Comment: How about the derivate ? BTW derivate of x^3 is 3^x2, not 3^x3

Comment: I need help with the code not with calculus...

Comment: Still, how about the derivate ? Would the user compute it him/herself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a new input and take in the function as a string. then pass that function to your `funcion` function and use `eval()` to evaluate it after replacing all occurences of `x` with the value the user entered.

Change your form to this:

```
<form name="formulario" onsubmit="return procesar(this);">
    Ingrese el valor
    <input name="x" type="text" size="4" />
    Ingrese la función
    <input name="func" type="text" size="15" />
    <input type="submit" value="Procesar" />
  </form>
```

and then change your `funcion` function to:

```
function funcion(func,x) {
  var newFunc = func.replace(/x/g,x);
  return eval(newFunc);
}
```

also add:

`var func = document.getElementsByName("func")[0].value;`

to handle the new input, and pass it as `function(func,x)` when you calculate your result

The last step is to calculate the derivative of the function your user entered. I suggest using a library like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/smath/wiki/smathJavaScriptAPI) to do the work.

see a live example (minus derivative) here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgEdGW